# Shopware6 - Productdetail Thumbnails - Change size

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I would like to change the size of the Thumbnails on the Productdetails-Page. At the moment the Thumbnails are very small. Whats the best way to set the size of to 200px width?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I need to change the thumbnails under Main-Image of the product in the product detail page.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the related twig file and setting explizit sizes. f.e.

```html
{% sw_thumbnails 'product-image-thumbnails' with {
    media: cover,
    sizes: {
        'default': '200px'
    }
} %}
```

Additionally and depending of your theme and installed plugins you might have to adjust CSS.

Comment: Thank you for this, but it does not work for the product-thumbnails on the product-detail-page. Which twig-File I have to modify?

Comment: this is twig file `Resources/views/storefront/element/cms-element-image-gallery.html.twig` 
you can find 
``` lang-twig
{% sw_thumbnails 'gallery-slider-image-thumbnails' with {
     media: image
} %}
```
extend that template and add default size you want to it: 
``` lang-twig
{% sw_thumbnails 'gallery-slider-image-thumbnails' with {
     media: image,
     sizes: {
           'default': '200px'
      } 
} %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use search-function of your IDE with term "product-image-thumbnail".

Then you'll see you have to decorate block `component_product_box_image` `storefront/component/product/card/box-standard.html.twig` to set the variable size.

Exampe file at `YourPluginFolder/src/Resources/views/storefront/component/product/card/box-standard.html.twig`:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/component/product/card/box-standard.html.twig' %}

{% block component_product_box_image %}
    {% set sizes = {
        'default': '200px'
    } %}
   {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This one does not work cause it changes the thumbnail on product listing page. I need to change the size of the thumbnails under the main-imange on the product detail page

Comment: Oh sorry. I missread. But the steps are maybe the same.
do you mean "gallery-slider-thumbnails-item-inner"?

Comment: Just set width and height via css onto class gallery-slider-thumbnails-item

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by customizing template:
`Resources/views/storefront/element/cms-element-image-gallery.html.twig`
you can find

```twig
{% sw_thumbnails 'gallery-slider-image-thumbnails' with {
     media: image
} %}
```

extend the block contains that code and add default size you want to it:

```twig
{% sw_thumbnails 'gallery-slider-image-thumbnails' with {
     media: image,
     sizes: {
           'default': '200px'
      } 
} %}
```

How to customize template: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/customize-templates#custom-template-content

Comment: This one does not work. It just changed the thumbnail of the main-image. I need to resize the thumbs under the main-image on product detail page.